# Filtering processes with top in FreeBSD

Tags: process, freebsd, top

➥ When using `top` utility to view processes and their activity, how does one filter the list to a subset by name?

For example when I want to see only the processes with a name containing `postgres` or `java`.

I am using FreeBSD 11.2, but guidance across Unix flavors would be helpful if behavior varies.

I have read about using this:

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' postgres)
```

…but I get an error:

> Illegal variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The `top` variant provided with *FreeBSD* core system **does not have** that `-p` option used to select a list of pid to watch on a pseudo real-time manner.

Nevertheless, the `htop` package can be installed on top of your *FreeBSD* system and this more colorfull top (among other things) variation have this wanted `-p` option.

- **`htop` help**:

From `htop` usage:

```
htop 2.2.0 - (C) 2004-2018 Hisham Muhammad
Released under the GNU GPL.

-C --no-color               Use a monochrome color scheme
-d --delay=DELAY            Set the delay between updates, in tenths of seconds
-h --help                   Print this help screen
-s --sort-key=COLUMN        Sort by COLUMN (try --sort-key=help for a list)
-t --tree                   Show the tree view by default
-u --user=USERNAME          Show only processes of a given user
-p --pid=PID,[,PID,PID...]  Show only the given PIDs
-v --version                Print version info
```

- **installing `htop`**

using *FreeBSD* repository:

```
# pkg install htop
```

or through the *ports*:

```
# cd /usr/ports/sysutils/htop
# make install clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Top in designed to show the top processes, hence the name. There are, however, some work arounds that might help you.

You can pipe the output to grep:

```
top | grep postgres
```

You could try the `-o` flag with a field name.

```
top -o pid
```

You can combine that with the `-i` flag, which takes you into interactive mode

```
top -io pid
```

Once there, you can toggle various options such as `a` for process titles, or `u` for user.

Try combining the various options.

**Reference**

```
man top
```

Freebsd 11.2 release

Comment: Helpful, but only a snapshot. I would like to see `top` running continually with fresh updates, but only for a subset of processes.

Comment: Also, this picks up processes where the *owner* is `postgres` rather than the *name* of the process itself containing “postgres”.

Comment: @BasilBourque I updated the answer. Hope that helps.